# Prevent form from scrolling up when click on textfield

Tags: android, ios, sencha-touch

I have a simple authentication form with two textfields and a login button (layout: xbox)
This form fits perfectly between the keyboard and the status bar when I'm editing the first textfield, but when I switch to the second textfield, the form scrolls up a bit.

Question : Does anyone know how to prevent the scrolling from happening ?

**[EDIT] Code**

```
app.views.UserLogin = function (config) {
    Ext.apply(this, config);

    this.loginField = new Ext.form.Text({
        cls: 'auth-login',
        width:"100%",
        allowBlank: false,
        placeHolder:'Identifiant',
        border:'0 0 1 0',
    });

    this.passwordField = new Ext.form.Password({
        cls: 'auth-password',
        width:"100%",
        allowBlank: false,
        placeHolder:'Mot de passe',
        border:'0',
    });

    this.loginBtn = new Ext.Button({
        width:"200px",
        text: "Connect",
        handler: this.onLoginBtnFn,
        scope: this,
        cls:'auth-button',
    });

    this.authFieldSet = new Ext.form.FieldSet({
        width:"90%",
        cls:'auth-fieldset',
        items:[this.loginField,this.passwordField]
    });

    //constructor
    app.views.UserLogin.superclass.constructor.call(this, {
        //dockedItems: [this.toolbar],
        fullscreen: true,
        cls:'auth',
        layout: 'vbox',
        items: [
            this.authFieldSet,
            this.loginBtn
        ]
    });
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us some more information? Is the form in a scroll view thats moving up? Possibly setting scrolling = NO; Maybe some code would help.

**Just to note Im talking about iOS development, I just released that you dont specify if your working in objective-c.**

Let me back up my answer a little so it makes more sense. The view controller should use these delegates   your probably already doing this.

Using the text field delegate alows access to the - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender and the - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField methods. When ttext field begins editing you can set scrollingEnabled = NO, and when the text field ends editing you can set scrollingEnabled = YES. It would look something like this:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
self.currentTextField = sender;
self.scrollView.scrollingEnabled = NO;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
self.currentTextField = nil;
self.scrollView.scrollingEnabled = YES;
}
```

**OR**

Another option is to add an observer, this is useful if your using TextViews instead of TextFields (Or a mixture of the two).

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:self.view.window]; 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:self.view.window]; 
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[_currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil]; 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil]; 
}
```

You do the same thing with this technique, in the keyboardWillShow method stop scrolling, and start it again in the keyboardWillHide method.

Hope Im helping at least a little.

Comment: scrolling = NO ? Where does that come from ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. You can disable scrolling in interface builder with a check box, OR progrmatically (as you would need) with:
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

Comment: That would be disable the scroll for the whole web view. I just want to disable the scrolling when you enter a text field.

Comment: I've tried to add the textfield delegate methods to my app delegate but they're never called. I assume this is because they're generated in Javascript and not in Obj-C ?

Comment: I dont know how Javascript would be called in this case. To get the delegate methods to be called (with any kind of delegate) you must tell the ViewController that it is the delegate by adding <UITextFieldDelegate> AND tell the text field who its delegat is, so you can do that in interface builder OR wherever you create your text field _myTextField.delegate = self; where 'self' is the view controller you just added <UITextFieldDelegate> to.

Comment: I did add the <UITextFieldDelegate> but since the input in not created with Objective-C, I can't set it's delegate to self...